# Django-admin-Filter Light

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin-filters

I am Using Django-admin-filter Light in my project. For some reason my dropdown and some other CSS is not working properly but not all.

I used

- dal
- dal_select2
- dal_admin_filter

and i think

- dal
- dal_select2

is not working

From  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autocomplete-light

in `views.py`

```
class DistrictAutoComplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated() or not self.request.user.is_superuser:

        return SchoolDistrictProfile.objects.none()

    qs = SchoolDistrictProfile.objects.all()

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

    return qs[:10]
```

and in `admin.py`

```
class DistrictFilter(AutocompleteFilter):
    title = 'Search and Select District'
    parameter_name = 'district'
    autocomplete_url = 'district-autocomplete'
```

Note :

> Css for adding the tags in the text field is not working.